# What is the correct method for showing a full screen photo within a mobile app using Unity?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, mobile

I am creating a mobile app using Unity. I would like to place a photo which fills the screen and then place some 3D objects on top of this photo. The photo is created during runtime and is saved to the persistance data folder.
What is the best method to achieve this? The options I see are Raw Image/Image/Sprite. However, I have been unable to achieve the above mentioned goal using either of these component types.

Answer (score 0):

What about making a panel on a canvas, setting the image as background and the canvas to fit screen size?
Then place the objects on front of it, manually or as children of said canvas but higher in the hierarchy.
I don't really understand what you intend to do, just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

editing my original answer: you need to use RawImage to be able to easily load images that are not marked as Sprite in the editor
You load images from file like this :

```
  Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1,1); // the following needs a non null starting poin
  var path=System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath,"your_file.jpg");
  byte[] bytes=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
  texture.LoadImage(bytes);

  rawImage.texture=texture;
```

As far as keeping it filling the screen the AspectRatioFiter component is likely to do the job

To get 3d objects rendering in front, set your canvas to 'Screen Space - Camera' and point it to your camera. This will behave similar to word space in regards to rendernig order (will get 3d sroted) but canvas size will match camera viewport, so AspectRatioFitter will be able to do its job

[image]

Comment: I would need more info than this to accept it as the answer. How do you propose to set the source of the Image component? The image bytes are stored in the persistent data folder. In what way do you suggest implementing the AspectRatioFiter?

Comment: @matwr I updated my answer to addres the second part of your question

Comment: I am currently already using the RawImage method  as this was the only method with which I was able to load from the file system. Although I am using persistant data path directly and do not referent System.IO. The main issue I have with this method is that 1. I am unable to set the size of the image within the context of the mobile display (it should be the same dimension as display -full screen) and 2. I am unable to position futher elements such as 3D objects over the image. The image always has a fixed size, smaller than the display and is always the outmost layer so it covers up 3D object

Comment: If you are able to demonstrate how to use RawImage to fill screen either by setting it's size or by using anchor points, etc. and how a 3D object can be placed over the image so that it is seen by the user, this would answer the question.